# why can you set __index equal to a table

Tags: lua, metatable, meta-method

The index metamethod can be set equal to tables. From what I can tell

```
foo.__index = function(self, k)
    return bar[k]
end
```

and

```
foo.__index = bar
```

are the same. Why is declaring functions this way allowed in this situation?

Comment: Have a look at the Lua string library for an example of when you would assign a table to __index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a function declaration - assigning a table to `__index` is just a shortcut for using the function that you described.

From [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) (for Lua 5.0, but this part of the language hasn't changed):

> The use of the __index metamethod for inheritance is so common that
>   Lua provides a shortcut. Despite the name, the __index metamethod does
>   not need to be a function: It can be a table, instead. When it is a
>   function, Lua calls it with the table and the absent key as its
>   arguments. When it is a table, Lua redoes the access in that table.

It's not like the table that you assign magically becomes a function. `type(foo.__index)` will still return `table`, and you can still do things with it that you can do with other tables, like using `pairs` and `next`, etc.

Comment: Using function does not allow list of `bar` fields when you have access to `foo` table.

Comment: That's true, yes - I suppose that means that this feature isn't technically syntactic sugar. I'll tweak my answer a little. :)